# How to prove the sequence $f_n(x)=(\sin (nx))^n $ on the interval $[0,\pi]$ is not almost everywhere convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How to prove the sequence $f_n(x)=(\sin (nx))^n$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$ is not almost everywhere convergent?

Comment: I'm not convinced it is. So far, the only points I can think of where the sequence doesn't converge are points of the form $\pi \cdot \frac {a}{2b}$ for integers $a,b$. This is definitely countable... Can you exhibit a non-rational point where the sequence fails to converge?

Comment: So am I, but I plot some irrational points in Mathematica and I think the conclusion may be true. However, I cannot prove it...

Comment: Is this a homework problem or something or just a conjecture? I'm interested now myself and will keep thinking about it, but I figure it's like this - the sequence fails to converge when there are 1's that appear arbitrarily far into the sequence. That means whatever the point is, it has to keep having terms appear of the form $(2n+1)\pi /2$. Unless there are other ways for the sequence to fail to converge, i.e. bounce around without hitting 1s somehow, then it must converge a.e.

But how it would bounce around with the exponent n... I don't see it.

Comment: If you could maybe post a sequence that goes on a long time without going to 0, that might help me think about why it fails for that value.

Comment: I think $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sin(n)^n)$ diverges.

Comment: Partial progress: It is (more or less) easy to see that $\Vert f_n\Vert_{L^p}\to 0$, so that $f_n \to 0$ in measure.